# PyCharm not finding conda pytorch

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to use PyCharm to edit a program that uses PyTorch, but the IDE is not finding the library.

The program runs from the command line, as the conda environment does have PyTorch installed:

```
(torch2) C:\>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\russe\Anaconda3\envs\torch2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
aom                       3.5.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
attrs                     22.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
...
python_abi                3.7                     3_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.12.1          cpu_py37h5e1f01c_1
pytz                      2022.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

But PyCharm is not seeing it:

[image]

I tried scrolling down in case it was listed under `torch`, but not there either.

Other, similar issues have been addressed here, but this does not seem to be one of them.

In [Mismatching Conda and Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909322/mismatching-conda-and-pycharm) the answer points to confusion between pip and conda in the PyCharm configuration. However, as you can see in the above screenshot, I definitely have PyCharm set to use conda; pip is not in the picture at all.

In [conda virtual environment not working with pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455571/conda-virtual-environment-not-working-with-pycharm) the top answer says

> This is a known issue in PyCharm on Windows at least. The conda environment is used but not actually activated by PyCharm so environment variables for the env are not loaded. It's been a problem for a while, seems it'd be easy to fix but for some reason they haven't fixed it.

> The only work around is to start PyCharm from a cmd window in which the env is activated, or possibly run the environment activation prior to execution as an external tool.

However, I have tried starting PyCharm from a cmd window in which the env is activated:

```
(torch2) C:\t>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\bin\pycharm64.exe"
```

and the problem persists.

Trying to change the path to the Python interpreter doesn't seem to work; the interpreter path field is not editable, and when I try to add a new Python interpreter, I just get this:

[image]

Comment: How do you install **pytorch** library? Using **pip install**? Or using **conda install**? You can try to click on the **green circle icon** (disable/enable) to show all the packages (from both pip and conda install). Normally it will only show the package you install from conda

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 Conda only. I have clicked the green circle, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Python environemnt** is at `C:\Users\russe\Anaconda3\envs\torch2`. So your Python Interpreter Executable should be at `C:\Users\russe\Anaconda3\envs\torch2\python.exe`

But in your photo, your Python Interpreter Executable is at `C:\Users\russe\Anaconda3\python.exe`, Please change to the right Python Interpreter

[image: Python Interpreter]

For example below is my Python Interpreter Executable named "recommended"
[image: mypath]

Also, you should create a **Conda Environment** by pointing to the **python.exe** file inside your **env folder** like below (maybe my UI is different from your, but idea is the same):

1. First, try to create a new virtual environment by clicking on this button
   [image: ...]
2. Then point to the python.exe file inside env folder
   [image: Conda Environment]

Comment: That sounds like it should be a promising approach, but it's not letting me change the path to the interpreter executable. Added details and screenshot explaining what I'm getting – it's not the same as what you're seeing.

Comment: @rwallace your UI is a bit different from my Pycharm (check my edited answer). Also, do you try **"Create new environment"** and try to point to the python.exe file inside your env folder?

Comment: If I click 'create new environment', there is nothing to point to a python.exe; the only thing it regards as variable is the location of the conda.bat.

Comment: You could try on "Load Environment" or other things. My point is, you should choose the right virtual env (torch2) for your Python interpreter, not the default Anaconda env